# Gap phenomenon vs Rigidity results for surfaces

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, conformal-geometry, geometric-analysis

I am trying to understand the differences between the rigidity results and gap results for a given surface immersed into some manifold. For instance, a Gap theorem  proved  [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/NYJM/JDGonline/p/2001/57-3-2.pdf) (Theorem 2.7) says that an immersed (Willmore) surface into $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a sphere or a plane under some conditions on the second fundamental form and its tracefree part. On the other, in [this article](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pmsc/126/02/0253-0260)
and [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.04761.pdf), rigidity results were proved for the Willmore surfaces immersed into a sphere $and$ an "ideal surface" into $\mathbb{R}^3$ $respectively$. So far, it seems the gap results and rigidity results are very similar and I'm trying to understand how these two terms (gap vs rigidity) differ when classifying surfaces via energy methods. Thanks

Comment: I'm unable to give a complete description of the semantic differences, but I wanted to add two examples to those listed. They are admittedly slightly orthogonal to the context you describe, but perhaps of interest nonetheless. 1. Epsilon-regularity results such as Schoen-Uhlenbeck's theorem are gap, but not really rigidity results. 2. A statement like 'An embedded minimal sphere in $\mathbf{S}^3$ is an equator' is a rigidity, but not a gap result.  ...

Comment: ... Perhaps more to the point, a generic statement like 'If the surface $\Sigma$ has energy at most that of a reference surface $\Sigma_0$, then $\Sigma$ is congruent to $\Sigma_0$' is a rigidity result in my eyes. However if the inequality $E(\Sigma) \leq E(\Sigma_0)$ imposed were replaced by something like $E(\Sigma) < E(\Sigma_0) + \delta_0$ then it would also be a gap result.

Comment: Often times one can prove a "gap" theorem from a "rigidity" theorem using a compactness argument. For example, if the "rigid" object is known to be isolated in some topology (e.g. by a linearization analysis) then one can try to take a sequence of solutions with slightly larger energy and show that eventually they have to enter that isolated neighborhood, contradiction. Of course, in many situations one cannot prove that the convergence is sufficiently strong to carry out this argument. Moreover, the most desirable gap theorem has a quantified constant, instead of one from compactness.